# Irregularity of $\{a^{b+cd} : d \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: regular-languages, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

I was solving some basic problems about the theory of machines and automata. The topic was about pumping lemma, but I could not solve the below question and prove that it is not regular.

$$L=\{a^{b+cd} \mid \text{$b$ and $c$ are constant, $d \in \{0,1,2,3,…\}$}\}$$

This is my incomplete solution:
Assume for contradiction that $L$ is a regular language. Since $L$ is infinite, we can apply the pumping lemma.
Let $p$ be the integer in the pumping lemma. Pick a string $w$ such that $w ∈ L$ and $|w| \ge p$.

Example: pick $a ^ {1 + p}$ and $b,c = 1$.
But now how should I get to a contradiction?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: How are $b,c$ quantified over? For any fixed $b,c$, your language is regular.

Comment: But can not we say in order that _d_ is infinite so the language will be infinite and it is not regular?@YuvalFilmus

Comment: A regular language can be infinite, the only thing that matters is that it can be recognized by a DFA/NFA or regular expression. You can convince yourself that your language is regular for fixed $b$ and $c$ by constructing a DFA with $b + c$ states that recognizes it.

Comment: ok, thanks. But sorry why the number of states is equal to $b + c$? And why we did not consider $d$?@plshelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the language is regular. Aside of counting $a$'s $b$ times, instead of thinking of counting $c$ times $d$ (counting a known number of times something unknown), we can think of counting $d$ times $c$ (counting an unknown number of times something known), of course. That is, we see $L$ as
$$
L = a^ba^{cd} = a^b({a^c})^d
$$
for two fixed $b$ and $c$.

We can draw a simple deterministic automaton for it:
[image: An automaton for the language L]

Furthermore, we can see that the language is context free, as we can show a context-free grammar for it:
\begin{align*} 
&S = B ~ D ~ . \\
&B = a^b. \\
&D = a^cD ~|~ \epsilon. 
\end{align*}

Then, since this language is defined on the singleton alphabet $\Sigma = \{a\}$, we know by [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem?wprov=sfla1) that this language is regular.

Answer (score 2):

For $b$ and $c$ fixed, this is a regular language. A corresponding regular expression would be $a^b(a^c)^*$.